# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Unable to deploy (Operation interrupted.)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

#### Problem Summary

After months of deploying, I've hit a snag with Firebase Cloud Functions.

```
firebase deploy --only functions --debug
```

Reveals a continual log dump of try and retry of Firebase Cloud Functions:

```
[functions] operation poll: [FUNCTION NAME] update operations/[LONG STRING] is not done
```

After about 15 minutes this process quits.  From the Cloud Functions log, I see several errors, all stating:

```
Operation interrupted.
```

#### How did I get into this state?

I was mid-deploy and quit mid-update. Since then, I can no longer recover.

#### What version of Firebase CLI

```
3.7.0
```

#### Expected result

Ability to deploy Firebase Cloud Functions.

#### What else have I tried?

1. Logging out and back in again.
2. Updating Cloud Functions code and re-dploy
3. Updating Firebase CLI

Comment: Appears related to our Cloud Function code.  I commented out a large block of code and was able to deploy again.  I believe the "How did I get into this state?" was a red herring.

Comment: I am getting the same error in all my functions, even in a test function with just a return line. They are working fine locally. Did you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this post;
[Cloud Functions for Firebase deploy interrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903381/firebase-cloud-functions-deploy-interrupted/43903568#43903568)
There are currently cloud function deployment issues. You can check the status here;
https://status.firebase.google.com/