# Cloud Functions for Firebase deploy interrupted

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Earlier it took me around 3-4 minutes to deploy functions to Firebase Cloud. Now when I'm trying to deploy my changes, CMD runs for good 10-15 minutes and then gives me this `Deploy Error: Operation interrupted` and a little message to my Cloud function log also saying `Operation interrupted`.
[image]

CMD and Log are not very helpful since they do not tell what is causing this problem. Is there something wrong with the code I made? It's very simple and I don't think that's causing the problem but here it is:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var roomID = "cheufer_923sfd98";

exports.findRoom = functions.database
    .ref('/Players Searching For Room/{uid}')
    .onWrite(event => {

        if(!event.data.exists())
        {
            return;
        }

        admin.database().ref('/Test Array/' + roomID).transaction(function(content){

            if(content == null)
            {
                content.push( {onGoing: false} );

                content.push( {players: [] } );
            }

            content.players.push(event.params.uid);

            return content;

        }, function(error, committed){

            if(committed)
            {
                console.log("Committed successfully. New data was inserted in table called 'TestArray'");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I am getting the same error in all my functions, even in a test function with nothing on it. Everything is working fine with the local emulator. Did the problem solve automatically or you had to do something?

Comment: I did nothing but waited. Problem was with Firebase as stated in the answer, not the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an incident with Cloud Functions deployments from 3:01pm to 5:23pm (PST) on 5/10/2017.  It has been resolved.

https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/17001